# How to deal with standard Error object on frontend?

Tags: javascript, api, error-handling

I have a frontend app with many API requests, but it's a pain to work with error responses.

Sometimes I need to go through many nested objects like: `error.response.data.email` and sometimes it is `error.response.data.address.province[0]`.

I can't predict all of the errors, and writing manual "parsers" looks like a dirty extra solution to me:

```
const errorsObject = err.response.data
    let errors = ''

    Object.keys(errorsObject).map(key => {
      if (key === 'address') {
        Object.keys(errorsObject.address).map(
          key => (errors += `${key} : ${errorsObject.address[key]}\n`)
        )
      } else {
        errors += `${key} : ${errorsObject[key]}\n`
      }
      return undefined
    })

    yield toast.error(errors)
```

Also it still doesn't cover everything.

Is there any frontend parsers for that? If not, our backend is Python(Django), maybe there is a package for backend side? Ideally I'd want to see a flat array of objects `{title, message}`.

Answer (score 5):

Your error objects are wellformed and the base idea of parsing the errors is right from a frontend perspective.

The only issues I see in your errors response is *nesting* and *hydration*.

If you want hydrated responses you should provide to your parser the feature of retrieving correctly data and eventually **map it to frontend UI**.

Usually I feed my forms with an object, usually called *errors* where I can safely retrieve the errors related to a field by its name.

IMHO you are doing it "right", try to work on object type instead of object specific key (like "address).

This is an example of a error parser I use very often. When a very deep nesting occurs or array parsing is needed, I usually update the parser to reach the error and gain the ability to retrieve it from my UI, for example to show the error under the field, border it in red and so on:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

export const getErrors = (errors) => {
  const validationErrors = _.get(errors, 'data.validation_messages') ? errors.data.validation_messages : {};
  // Iterate over object keys
  _.forOwn(validationErrors, (value, key) => {
    // Simple error: { key: { errorKey: value }} - Nested Error {key: { nestedErrorKey: { errorKey: value }}
    const data = validationErrors[key][Object.keys(validationErrors[key])[0]];
    // Check that content of key is neither null or object (nested validation)
    if (validationErrors[key] !== null && typeof data !== 'object') {
      validationErrors[key] = _.values(value)[0];
    } else if (validationErrors[key] !== null && typeof data === 'object') { // TODO: Recursive approach ?
      // Trasform nested values so obj: { nestedKey: nestedvalue } becomes obj_nestedKey: nestedValue
      _.forOwn(validationErrors[key], (nestedValue, nestedKey) => {
        validationErrors[`${key}_${nestedKey}`] = _.values(nestedValue)[0];
      });
    }
  });
  return validationErrors;
};

export default getErrors;
```

Comment: Thank for understanding my struggle! I thought there is some kind of common practice or even ready-solution, but seems like I have to still parse stuff.

Comment: It strongly depends on the standards your API eventually met (mine usually is HAL), but the core concept is to act on the frontend side, without touching the backend response. When you'll work for enough time with your parser on a standard of API you are done for parsing any API produced on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project, every error has an error code coming in the response and on the frontend side, every error code gets mapped with error messages, which was very easy to provide multi-locale error messages. You can try that if you have control on APIs and add one more key as error_code.